# Cannot get correct result when using variables to do calculation in js

Tags: javascript, calculation

So i was trying to create some "app" for fun to develop my one-week js skills. Its harder than it looks! But its very intresting. So, i came across the most odd difficulty i would think of:

When i use normal numbers in the calculation to the last lines, the result is normal, when one of the two variables is there, the calculations are very very strage (wrong, obviously). I searched a lot for a solution but nothing has helped me.

```js
var Alankylosaurus_stats = {
    hp: 4200,
    armor: .3,
    dmg: 900,
    speed: 110,
    crit: 5
};
var Allosinosaurus_stats = {
    hp: 4500,
    armor: .15,
    dmg: 1500,
    speed: 110,
    crit: 20
};
function dinoStats(x) {
    var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById('level_select_' + x).value);
    var dif = 26 - y;
    var dino = document.getElementById('dino_select_' + x).value;

    console.log(dif);
    if (dino === 'Alankylosaurus') {
        document.getElementById('table_hp_' + x).innerHTML = 
        Math.round( Alankylosaurus_stats.hp / (1.05 ^ dif));
    };
    if (dino === 'Allosinosaurus') {
        document.getElementById('table_hp_' + x).innerHTML = 
        Math.round( Allosinosaurus_stats.hp / (1.05 ^ dif));
    };

};
```

```html
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">
            <label for="level_select_left">Choose level:</label>
            <select id="level_select_left" onchange="dinoStats('left')">
                <option value="1">--Please choose--</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="26" selected>26</option>
            </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="5">
        <label for="dino_select_left">Choose Dino:</label>
        <select id="dino_select_left" onchange="dinoPick('left')">
            <option value="">--Please choose--</option>
            <option value="Alankylosaurus">Alankylosaurus</option>
            <option value="Allosinosaurus" selected>Allosinosaurus</option>
            <option value="Ankyntrosaurus">Ankyntrosaurus</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

html is not really necessary but i just use it to talk less :p

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 1.05 ^ dif
```

is not what you think. `^` is the binary xor operator, which will give you some strange values here, instead you want the exponation operator `**`:

```
1.05 ** dif
```

Comment: what a silly mistake... thanks! i am curious though, do you know why it will give me correct results without using variables, but when variables are involved it behaves strange?